What subspace induces a normal subgroup of the fundamental group of the whole space?
If $A$ is a retract of a path-connected topological space $X$, let $h_\iota: \pi(A)\to \pi(X)$ be the group homomorphism of fundamental groups, induced by inclusion $\iota: A\to X$. Then the image $h_\iota(\pi(A))$ is a subgroup of the whole space fundamental group $\pi(X)$. So under what condition, is the image a normal subgroup?
I know if $A$ is a deformation retract, the inclusion induces an isomorphism of their fundamental groups. So need to exclude that situation.
Does it have to be that $X=A\times B$, or that $X=X_1\times X_2$ where $A$ is a deformation retract of, say, $X_1$? Thanks.

I'm not sure there's a meaningful general condition, but certainly a lot more can happen than the inclusion of a product factor. The subgroup is automatically normal if $\pi_1(X)$ is abelian or $\pi_1(A)=0$, for example. Another fun thing you can do is take $A,B$ be compact manifolds s.t. $\dim(A)+\dim(B)\ge3$. Then $A\times B-{pt}$ has the same fundamental group as $A\times B$ (and still contains copies of $A$ and $B$ as retracts), yet cannot be written as a product.
